# Format dateTime as string for artifact name in Azure DevOps Pipelines & Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to use a dateTime as my file name for an Azure DevOps Artifact, but it messes with me..

I'm fetching a datetime from a json with powershell, exsposing to my pipeline with `##vso[task.setvariable variable=Version;]$version`

Output from local test is `##vso[task.setvariable variable=Version;]2022-09-15T07:40:17Z.`

But when i echo from pipeline:

```
$(version)
09/15/2022
07:40:17
```

Witch means the folder structure for the artifact is a mess from '/'

[Foder structure for artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ5t5.png)

I have tried to replacet both the - from powershell, and / from the pipeline without success.

Any idea how i can simply use the date and time as my name for the artifact?

Comment: You can use the `-Format` parameter of `Get-Date` to output a String object instead of a DateTime object. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date#-format

Comment: Can you show the json file you're loading the ```$version``` variable from, and how you're populating ```$version```? If you're reading it from json the value is probably a *string*, so it it's in the wrong format you might need to parse it to ```[datetime]``` and then re-serialize it with the format you want (or at the very least, do some funky string manipulation)...